# KOTLIN Why when i changed a List it is also accidentally changing another list

Tags: android, list, kotlin

Hello i want to know why is my program changing selectedDataEdited List when i only changing editTransactionList ?

```kotlin
var editTransactionList: MutableList<Transaction>? = mutableListOf()
var selectedDataEdited: List<Transaction>? = listOf()

editTransactionList = listTest as MutableList<Transaction>
selectedDataEdited = listTest

var position = 0

println("edit $editTransactionList")
println("select $selectedDataEdited")

editTransactionList.get(position).apply {
    amount = 2000
    name = "K"
}
println("edit $editTransactionList")
println("select $selectedDataEdited")

editTransactionList.get(position).apply {
    amount = 3000
    name = "Z"
}
println("edit $editTransactionList")
println("select $selectedDataEdited")
```

the output is

```
edit [Transaction(amount=1000, name=T, test=1)]
select [Transaction(amount=1000, name=T, test=1)]
edit [Transaction(amount=2000, name=K, test=1)]
select [Transaction(amount=2000, name=K, test=1)]
edit [Transaction(amount=3000, name=Z, test=1)]
select [Transaction(amount=3000, name=Z, test=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are basically references. When you store an object in a variable you actually say "when using this variable please refer to this object". So if you "store" the same object into 2 different variables, each of them still refers to that same object. Getting the object using the first variable, making changes to  it, and then accessing the second variable, will still get you that changed object.

You will need to copy the list to prevent the unwanted behavior. Keep in mind though that you would probably need a deep copy. Simply calling `toList()` on it for example only makes a shallow copy, which means that even though it will be a different list, the objects inside it will still refer to the original.

It's hard to tell what would work without knowing what `Transaction` looks like. If `Transaction` is a data class then `selectedDataEdited = listTest.map { it.copy() }` might work. See this example https://pl.kotl.in/Q_o8pYXVs

Comment: i've already call "selectedDataEdited = listTest.toList()" but selectedDataEdited still changing

Comment: @ToganJ.R that's what I explained. I specifically said that `toList()` would not be enough

Comment: @ToganJ.R It's hard to tell what would work without knowing what `Transaction` looks like. If `Transaction` is a data class then `selectedDataEdited = listTest.map { it.copy() }` might work.

Comment: the transaction is something like this ,     
`var testNew = Transaction(1000,"T",1)
    var listTest: MutableList<Transaction> = mutableListOf()
    listTest.add(testNew)`
ok, ill try using copy

Comment: i already tested using it.copy , it still changing selectedDataEdited, was missreading output before mb sorry

Comment: @ToganJ.R I don't know why it doesn't work for you then. Look at this example and it works correct: https://pl.kotl.in/Q_o8pYXVs

Answer (score 1):

If `selectedDataEdited = listTest.map { it.copy() }` is not working, try below code:

```
 listedTest.forEach {
        selectedData.add(Transaction(amount = it.amount, name = it.name, test = it.test))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> KOTLIN Why when i changed a List it is also accidentally changing another list

Because you don't have "another" list. You only have one list.

When you do `selectedDataEdited = listTest`, you assign a second reference to the same list. If you want two separate lists, you must create them, possibly by cloning the original list.

Comment: how to clone the original list ? because i've tested using .toList() and it is still changing

Comment: @ToganJ.R I would start by googling "kotlin clone list"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `as MutableList` use `toMutableList`:

```
editTransactionList = listTest.toMutableList()
```

It will make a copy of your list instead of passing a reference to the same list.